# Prove that the tangent plane in $(u_{0},v_0)$ is the same as the "parameterized plane" $(u,v)\rightarrow\Phi(u_0,v_0)+D\Phi(u_0,v_0) (u-u_0,v-v_0)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ describe a parameterized surface, where $\Phi$ is differentiable. Prove that the tangent plane in $(u_{0},v_0)$ is the same as the "parameterized plane"

$$(u,v)\rightarrow\Phi(u_0,v_0)+D\Phi(u_0,v_0)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
u-u_0\\
v-v_0\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

I have the next:

Let's consider $\Phi(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)$
We can define the tangent plane in $(u_0,v_0)$ as $\Phi(u_0,v_0)+sT_u+tT_v$ where
$T_u=(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial u})$ and
$T_v=(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial y}{\partial v},\frac{\partial z}{\partial v})$
(both of them evaluated in $(u_0,v_0)$)

Now:
$$\Phi(u_0,v_0)+D\Phi(u_0,v_0)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
u-u_0\\
v-v_0\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=
\Phi(u_0,v_0)+
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)_{(u_0,v_0)}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
u-u_0\\
v-v_0\\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=
\Phi(u_0,v_0)+T_u(u-u_o)+T_v(v-v_0)=
\Phi(u_0,v_0)+uT_u+vT_v+u_0T_u+v_0T_v$$

As we can see $\Phi(u_0,v_0)+uT_u+vT_v+u_0T_u+v_0T_v$ looks very similar to $\Phi(u_0,v_0)+sT_u+tT_v$ but I don't know how to get rid of $u_0T_u+v_0T_v$ or how to interpret them.

Can you please give me some ideas or tell me if I'm in the correct way